# why $H_{1}(\Sigma)\cong H_{1}(Sym^{g}(\Sigma))$ ?

Tags: floer-homology

In paper holomorphic disks and 3-manifold invariants,  Ozsvath  and Szabo  connstruct two 
homeomoephisms 
 $\mathcal {f} : H_{1}(\Sigma)\rightarrow H_{1}(Sym^{g}(\Sigma))$ and 
 $\mathcal {g} : H_{1}(Sym^{g}(\Sigma))\rightarrow H_{1}(\Sigma)$. 
Then they says these two maps are inverses of each other.

Sorry for my weak ability,  I can not see how this work. So can somebody explain it, like  what f or g maps the generator to ? And why these two maps are inverses of each other? Thank you.

Comment: You may want to give a precise reference, or explain the notation...


Comment: This question is answered here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45923/question-on-the-symmetric-product-mathrmsymg-sigma

Comment: Mariano is absolutely right that the notation should be explained in the question, but from the link that Will gave, I gather that $\Sigma$ is a genus $g$ Riemann surface. So the result also follows by noting that $Sym^g\Sigma$ is birational to a $g$-dimensional complex torus by
the Abel-Jacobi theorem, and that $H_1$ is birational invariant.

Comment: en, suppose $C$ is a representing closed curve in $H_{1}(Sym^{g}(\Sigma))$, what is the $g(C)$?

Comment: Yanqing, the inverse to $f$ [$g$ is not a good letter to choose!] is outlined by Jim Conant in the answer linked to by Will. If $\gamma\colon S^1\to Sym^g(\Sigma)$ is a smooth loop, transverse to the diagonal (hence disjoint from it), the $g$ points in $\gamma(t)$, for varying $t$, trace out a 1-manifold $T$ which comes with two maps: a $g$-fold covering map $T \to S^1$ (this orients $T$) and a map $T\to \Sigma$. Take the fundamental class of $T$ in $H_1(\Sigma)$. 